# How to set `lock_timeout` on a PostgreSQL connection with SQLAlchemy and psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

With PostgreSQL, you can run this query to set a specific `lock_timeout` for a session:

```sql
SET lock_timeout TO '3s'
```

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to set this option when setting up a connection with SQLAlchemy. The way I'm instantiating SQLAlchemy sessions is the following:

```py
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pswd}@{host}:{port}/{name}')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

I've tried passing it in `connect_args` but that is not supported:

```py
engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pswd}@{host}:{port}/{name}',
    connect_args={'lock_timeout': 3}
)
```

Is there a way to set this option per-session/connection with SQLAlchemy and psycopg2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turned out, this is the right way to set `lock_timeout` for a session (note that the value is in milliseconds):

```py
engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pswd}@{host}:{port}/{name}',
    connect_args={'options': '-c lock_timeout=3000'}
)
```

Comment: Does the `connect_args={'lock_timeout': 3}` method not work or it is not the right way to do it? Also, can you share the link to some documentation, I am not about this find this way: `{'options': '-c lock_timeout=3000'}` of passing arguments anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @KshitijMittal it's somewhat tricky. No, "bare" lock_timeout: 3 is not the right way. lock_timeout is one of options as described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS (look for "options" param). So "options" is a "connection argument" that wraps another format for defining "options". "options" in general are described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html and lock_timeout in particular at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT.

Comment: ... and the whole "-c" form is mentioned at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html.